# How to split a sequence in k homogeneous parts?

Tags: r, algorithm, split, hierarchical-clustering

I'd like to split a sequence into k parts, and optimize the homogeneity of these sub-parts.

```
Example : 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 2 3 3 3 2 2 3 2 1 0 0 0
Result  : 0 0 0 0 0 | 1 1 2 | 3 3 3 2 2 3 2 | 1 0 0 0 when you ask for 4 parts (k = 4)
```

Here, the algorithm did not try to split in fixed-length parts, but instead tried to make sure elements in the same parts are as homogeneous as possible.

What algorithm should I use ? Is there an implementation of it in R ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. K-means kind of works (that is what I started with), but you have to make sure the values (0 to 3 in my example) are small when compared to position (which delta is 1). Indeed, k-means could decide to cluster points that are not neighbors if their position is far but their value is close.

Comment: Input and result values have different values. In 3rd part

Comment: solved, thanks Santi Gil

Comment: Ok, let me answer with your example, maybe it is helpful.

Comment: This can be done in O(nk) time with dynamic programming, *but you need to specify the precise measure of homogeneity to be optimised*.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use [Expectation-maximization algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm). Your points would be `(value, position)`. In your example, this would be something like:

[image: Example]

With the E-M algorithm, the result would be something like (by hand):

[image: Solution]

This is the desired output, so you can consider using this, and if it really works in all your scenarios. An annotation, you must assign previously the number of clusters you want, but I think it's not a problem for you, as you have set out your question.

Let me know if this worked ;)

**Edit:**

See this picture, is what you talked about. With k-means you should control the `delta value`, this is, how the **position** increment, to have its value to the same scale that **value**. But with E-M this doesn't matter.

[image: Delta increment]

**Edit 2:**

Ok I was not correct, you need to control the `delta value`. It is not the same if you increment **position** by 1 or by 3: (two clusters)

[image: Difference]

Thus, as you said, this algorithm could decide to cluster points that are not neighbours if their position is far but their value is close. You need to guarantee this not to happen, with a high increment of `delta`. I think that with a increment of **2 * (max - min)** values of your sequence this wouldn't happen.

Now, your points would have the form `(value, delta * position)`.

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed answer.

K-means and EM are quite similar as you illustrated in this answer. Moreover, their approach is two-dimensional by design, where the problem is a sequence. I think we could find a better approach to the problem, maybe more specific, but I will stick with this one for the moment.

Thanks